# Auto populate empty host folders with container content?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

In Docker Compose, when I mount an empty host volume to a location that already has data in the container, than this data is copied to the empty host volume on the first run.

E.g. if I use the nginx image and mount my empty host volume `nginx-config` to `/etc/nginx` in the nginx container then on the first start of the container everything from `/etc/nginx` is copied to my host volume `nginx-config`.

Meanwhile I am using Kubernetes and wondering how that's done in kubernetes? When I mount a empty PersistentVolume to an container at `/etc/nginx`, nothing is automatically copied to it ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an initContainer, mount the volume on a different path and do the copy explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but how do I mount the "real" container on the init container, to read its files (`/etc/nginx`)?

Comment: You would run the real container as the init container with an override on the command to instead be cp -r. Kubernetes does not support data containers like Docker does.